# Creating psql dump with row level security on runtime parameter (app.some_parameter)

Tags: postgresql, psql, pg-dump, row-level-security

I have a db schema with PSQL tables with RLS enabled with policies like:

```sql
CREATE POLICY some_policy ON some_table
USING (some_column = current_setting(app.some_parameter));
```

I want to create a dump where I can use this policy.
Is it possible to set the parameter `app.some_parameter` for the pg_dump command?
Or, is there any workaround?

Best would be to have something like:

```
pg_dump ... --data-only --enable-row-security --parameters="app.some_parameter=123"
```

Answer (score 2):

After further investigation I found out that the configuration parameters can be set with environment variables for pg_dump. An example:

```
env PGOPTIONS="-c app.some_parameter=123" pg_dump ... --data-only --enable-row-security ...
```

With this the policies can be used.